# Issue on Creating Group Buttons

Tags: css

I am trying to create a Vertical and Horizontal Group buttons at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/HNtf5/1/) but not able to remove the space between the `button-group-v` group buttons! and also there is overlapping border between `button-group-h` buttons (at Top and Bottom of the Middle). Can you please let me know if this is a correct solution to create a group buttons? if so can you please let me know how I can solve the above mentioned issues?

```
<ul class="button-group-v">
    <li><button class="btn button">Button</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn button">Button</button></li> 
    <li><button class="btn button">Button</button></li>
</ul>

<ul class="button-group-h">
    <li><button class="btn button">Button</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn button">Button</button></li> 
    <li><button class="btn button">Button</button></li>
</ul>


.btn {
    background: #d2f21b;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin:0px;
    border:none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.button-group-v, .button-group-v li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0px;
}

.button-group-h, .button-group-h li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline elements are sensitive to white space. Simply remove it:

```
<ul class="button-group-v">
    <li><button class="btn button">Button</button></li><li><button class="btn button">Button</button></li><li><button class="btn button">Button</button></li>
</ul>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HNtf5/2/)**

Another options is to ignore the white space by using HTML comments:

```
<ul class="button-group-v">
    <li>
        <button class="btn button">Button</button>
    </li><!--
    --><li>
        <button class="btn button">Button</button><!--
    </li><!--
    --><li>
        <button class="btn button">Button</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/c3s5e/)**

You could also float the list items left, but that would also require clearing the first element that came after the list.

As for the vertical list not having spacing between elements, that's due to `margin:0px;` on `.btn`.